# Firebase query for single value update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to add listener for a single value change on Firebase database. I tried below code but it listen on every value change.

```
 mFirebaseDatabase.child("url").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(<url>);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method, like in the following lines of code:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child("url").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        //Get desired data from dataSnapshot object
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
```